# holdout collection works strange when the contained objects have same material

Tags: collections

I am having a problem about holdout a collection.

Like below, i put cube and cone in the scene, and cone in another collection to let it holdout.
And if cube and cone are assigned same material, both get holdout.( cube are not in the same collection with cone though...)
[image]

If I prepare different material for cone, it works properly.
[image]

I wish to know why material effects to holdout.

Comment: To me it looks like a bug, not a feature.

Comment: thank you for the comment.   I will prepare same material with different name for cone.